# Alternative to using "pass" in a single-line "if/else" statement?

Tags: python

I would like to conditionally `print` a statement as such:

```
be_nice = True

print("Hello")
print("Good to see you!") if be_nice else pass
```

However, it seems that using `pass` here isn't allowed.

I found two ways to work around this, I can either do:

```
print("Good to see you!") if be_nice else 1
```

which seems to work since the `1` here simply does nothing, but is ugly. Or I can:

```
if be_nice: print("Good to see you!")
```

but this defeats the purpose of having the `print`'s align with each other.

Is there a way to use a single line solution which has the `print` called at the start of the line?

Comment: You're complaining about some Pythonisms that I think you're just going to have to get used to. I'd argue you want the `if` to stand out as that is conditional logic and impacts the flow. There's nothing worse than thinking code will always run only to find some trailing `if` off-screen you need to scroll to see.

Comment: *"Is there a way to use a single line solution which has the print called at the start of the line?"* - Yes, you already showed one.

Comment: @tadman So why is something like `my_var = 23 if some_long_condition else 42`  possible? One may argue that this too can result in a long line with a trailing `if` off-screen and cause readability issues as you point out.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, but I am looking for something that does nothing and is as Pythonic as `pass`

Comment: Missed the last line of the question, it's indeed a bad idea to try to do what OP wants to do.

Comment: Using the ternary operator (`x if c else y`) for side effects (print) seems weird to me.  I would stick with `if c: print(...)`.  Worth noting that PEP 8 encourages you to put the print call on a new line, not the same line as the if statement (see https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations).  If you must use the ternary operator then using pass seems a sensible way to do it.

Comment: @KellyBundy When there's "surprise `if` conditions", equally, yes.

Comment: I'm just stating a preference, not a rule. I like to see branches laid out via indentation, though there are cases where an inline `if` works, like `[x for y in z if ...]` though this is mostly because you can spread this out over multiple lines for clarity.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think the question is clear enough. All I want is something similar to `print("Good to see you!") if be_nice else 1` with something that looks better than the `1` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like, according what I was able to find in to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions), that you use the only way to do it.

The documentation say :

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, C rather
> than x. If C is true, x is evaluated and its value is returned;
> otherwise, y is evaluated and its value is returned.

You can't use `pass` as `y` value because :

> pass is a null operation — when it is executed, nothing happens.
>
> [Python pass documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-pass_stmt)

`pass` is an operator so no value is return to evaluate `x` if `C` is equals to `false`.

---

If you want you can possibly use the Ellipsis object (`...`) as `y` value :

```
be_nice = True

print("Hello") print("Good to see you!") if be_nice else ...
```

Effectively the Ellipsis is an object so a value.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do) more information about the Ellipsis object.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, I suggest writing your own print function. Here are some "not terrible" options:

```py
import functools as ft

be_nice = True

def print_if(cond, *args, **kwargs):
    if cond:
        print(*args, **kwargs)

print_if(be_nice, "Hello World")

print_if_be_nice = ft.partial(print_if, be_nice)
print_if_be_nice("Hello World")


def cond_print(*args, cond=False, **kwargs):
    if cond:
        print(*args, **kwargs)


cond_print("Hello World", cond=be_nice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
print("Good to see you!\n" if be_nice else "", end="")
```