# What do ellipses do when they are the default argument of a function?

Tags: python

In pandas source code, here's a snippet of the `to_csv` function:

```
@overload
    def to_csv(
        self,
        path_or_buf: FilePath | WriteBuffer[bytes] | WriteBuffer[str],
        sep: str = ...,
        na_rep: str = ...,
        float_format: str | Callable | None = ...,
```

What does the `...` mean?

**EDIT:**
A couple of users have suggested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do).
Though appreciated, as per my comment, this answer does not contain a clear explanation of `...` used as function argument defaults. There is a discussion [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50661182/12705481), but it is not concrete enough for me to consider it satisfactory, and so I rejected the suggestion to close my question as having been answered elsewhere.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you found that particular piece of code? If I look at the source of `to_csv()` here (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L3720-L3919), as it is linked from the pandas doc here (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), no ellipsis is used in the actual source code.

Comment: @simon just right above the spot you linked, at L3694. There's another `to_csv` function.

Comment: @Alan Oh, I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @OlivierNeve... there's a suggestion in there that `...` serves the same function as `None` in this context, but nothing too concrete. So I wouldn't consider my question answered.

Comment: Looks like that use of `...` is linked to the `@overload` decorator. In this context, seems to mean "for default, see actual implementation".

Comment: ok then, hope you get answers for what you are looking for!

Comment: Afraid not @JonSG. This answer was already linked by @Oliver Neve. I read through the answers on this question, and this was the only one that referenced ellipses as argument defaults. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50661182/12705481

And the best it gives is the suggestion that they work the same as `None`. But nothing is very concrete. For example, are there contexts where they do NOT work the same as `None`.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189281/202168 and the second link in your question both explain what the ellipsis does. It's a placeholder object that is _distinct from_ `None`, so e.g. it is quite common to have `None` as the default arg for a function, but here they want to say "there is a default arg value but we don't know or want to specify what it is". So they can't use `None` to mean "no definition" because that could be the actual specific value, but they can use the ellipsis instead.

Comment: You can use `...` as the default arg value in your own methods even if they are not defined as `@overload` and what the value of `...` means inside the body of your method is up to you - it's just a singleton `Ellipsis` object (like `None`)

Comment: The python3.0 notes have this to say _"**The ellipsis (...) can be used as an atomic expression anywhere**. (Previously it was only allowed in slices.)"_ per : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/66d1d7eb067d445f1ade151f4a6db3864dd9109f/Doc/whatsnew/3.0.rst#L444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer**: in this particular case, the ellipsis (`...`) is used as a placeholder for the default values in an overloaded method signature, following [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) ("In stubs it may be useful to declare an argument as having a default without specifying the actual default value. … In such cases the default value may be specified as a literal ellipsis").

**The long answer**: In its current version, the `to_csv()` method provides two overloads – see source code starting [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L3666). An "overloaded function" (or method) in Python simply means a different combination of input and return types, or even a different number of arguments, for the sake of type annotation. It is provided as a stubbed definition that is marked by the `@overload` decorator – see the section of the corresponding PEP 484 [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading).

At present, this looks as follows for `to_csv()`:

```py
    @overload
    def to_csv(
        self,
        path_or_buf: None = ...,
        sep: str = ...,
        na_rep: str = ...,
        float_format: str | Callable | None = ...,
        columns: Sequence[Hashable] | None = ...,
        header: bool_t | list[str] = ...,
        index: bool_t = ...,
        index_label: IndexLabel | None = ...,
        mode: str = ...,
        encoding: str | None = ...,
        compression: CompressionOptions = ...,
        quoting: int | None = ...,
        quotechar: str = ...,
        lineterminator: str | None = ...,
        chunksize: int | None = ...,
        date_format: str | None = ...,
        doublequote: bool_t = ...,
        escapechar: str | None = ...,
        decimal: str = ...,
        errors: OpenFileErrors = ...,
        storage_options: StorageOptions = ...,
    ) -> str:
        ...

    @overload
    def to_csv(
        self,
        path_or_buf: FilePath | WriteBuffer[bytes] | WriteBuffer[str],
        sep: str = ...,
        na_rep: str = ...,
        float_format: str | Callable | None = ...,
        columns: Sequence[Hashable] | None = ...,
        header: bool_t | list[str] = ...,
        index: bool_t = ...,
        index_label: IndexLabel | None = ...,
        mode: str = ...,
        encoding: str | None = ...,
        compression: CompressionOptions = ...,
        quoting: int | None = ...,
        quotechar: str = ...,
        lineterminator: str | None = ...,
        chunksize: int | None = ...,
        date_format: str | None = ...,
        doublequote: bool_t = ...,
        escapechar: str | None = ...,
        decimal: str = ...,
        errors: OpenFileErrors = ...,
        storage_options: StorageOptions = ...,
    ) -> None:
        ...

    @final
    @doc(
        storage_options=_shared_docs["storage_options"],
        compression_options=_shared_docs["compression_options"] % "path_or_buf",
    )
    def to_csv(
        self,
        path_or_buf: FilePath | WriteBuffer[bytes] | WriteBuffer[str] | None = None,
        sep: str = ",",
        na_rep: str = "",
        float_format: str | Callable | None = None,
        columns: Sequence[Hashable] | None = None,
        header: bool_t | list[str] = True,
        index: bool_t = True,
        index_label: IndexLabel | None = None,
        mode: str = "w",
        encoding: str | None = None,
        compression: CompressionOptions = "infer",
        quoting: int | None = None,
        quotechar: str = '"',
        lineterminator: str | None = None,
        chunksize: int | None = None,
        date_format: str | None = None,
        doublequote: bool_t = True,
        escapechar: str | None = None,
        decimal: str = ".",
        errors: OpenFileErrors = "strict",
        storage_options: StorageOptions | None = None,
    ) -> str | None:
        # Actual doc and source of the method follow
```

Note that the only difference between the first and second overload is the combination of `path_or_buf` argument and the return type:

- In the first case, `path_or_buf` is `None` and the return type will be `str` (namely, as no path is given, the resulting CSV data will be returned).
- In the second case, `path_or_buf` is something writeable (a file path or some buffer) and the return type will be `None` (as the CSV data is written to the path or buffer, it does not need to be returned).

The default values of arguments do not matter at this point, so they are simply abbreviated as an ellipsis. This, again, follows PEP 484, which [specifies](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values):

> In stubs it may be useful to declare an argument as having a default without specifying the actual default value. … In such cases the default value may be specified as a literal ellipsis.

This seems to be a good choice for several reasons:

- Syntactically, this is just fine, as the ellipsis, as of Python 3, is an ordinary Python object.
- For a human reader, it is convenient to read; also, it avoids using `None` for the same purpose, which would be ambiguous (as in: does it mean "I don't care about the actual value at this point" or does it mean "the default value is None"?).
- For the Python interpreter, it does not make a difference, as it takes its default values from the final signature that precedes the actual code. (This final signature, the third one in the given case, also combines the type annotations for `path_or_buf` and the return type from the previous two cases, so it is not immediately clear from the type annotations alone, which combinations are possible – which is why `@overload` was used in the first place).

One might wonder why the ellipses are provided here at all – in fact, the code seems to run just as well without them (except for the ones that replace the method body in the stubs). However, as pointed out by @tobias_k, they help with another distinction, regarding the overloads: in the way the ellipses are used, they indicate that a default value is actually part of *this particular overload*. Note the `path_or_buf` argument: its default value is only meaningful for the first overload (`path_or_buf` is `None`), but not for the second (a path or buffer must be provided by the caller). Consequently, an ellipsis is only present in the first overload's signature but not in the second overload's signature for this particular argument.

Comment: Pretty much what I wanted to write, including the "not really sure" note. About the missing default-`...`: I think this was on purpose, indicating that in the first overload, the path is expected to be `None`, and in the second it _has no default_ (if no value is passed, the first overload would be used).

Comment: @tobias_k Ooh, good catch! Thanks! I will try and rephrase this.