# What is the difference between ellipsis and pass in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ellipsis

Is there any difference between `...` or Ellipsis and `pass` in python? I only found out about it when I was looking through pygame 2.5.0 (installed version). I learned that we use `pass` to make a function do nothing. This is the file I first found it in:
`image.pyi`:

```py
from typing import Optional, Sequence, Tuple, Union

from pygame.bufferproxy import BufferProxy
from pygame.surface import Surface
from ._common import FileArg, Literal

_BufferStyle = Union[BufferProxy, bytes, bytearray, memoryview]
_to_string_format = Literal[
    "P", "RGB", "RGBX", "RGBA", "ARGB", "BGRA", "RGBA_PREMULT", "ARGB_PREMULT"
]
_from_buffer_format = Literal["P", "RGB", "BGR", "BGRA", "RGBX", "RGBA", "ARGB"]
_from_string_format = Literal["P", "RGB", "RGBX", "RGBA", "ARGB", "BGRA"]

def load(filename: FileArg, namehint: str = "") -> Surface: ...
def save(surface: Surface, filename: FileArg, namehint: str = "") -> None: ...
def get_sdl_image_version(linked: bool = True) -> Optional[Tuple[int, int, int]]: ...
def get_extended() -> bool: ...
def tostring(
    surface: Surface, format: _to_string_format, flipped: bool = False
) -> bytes: ...
def fromstring(
    bytes: bytes,
    size: Union[Sequence[int], Tuple[int, int]],
    format: _from_string_format,
    flipped: bool = False,
) -> Surface: ...
# the use of tobytes/frombytes is preferred over tostring/fromstring
def tobytes(
    surface: Surface, format: _to_string_format, flipped: bool = False
) -> bytes: ...
def frombytes(
    bytes: bytes,
    size: Union[Sequence[int], Tuple[int, int]],
    format: _from_string_format,
    flipped: bool = False,
) -> Surface: ...
def frombuffer(
    bytes: _BufferStyle,
    size: Union[Sequence[int], Tuple[int, int]],
    format: _from_buffer_format,
) -> Surface: ...
def load_basic(filename: FileArg) -> Surface: ...
def load_extended(filename: FileArg, namehint: str = "") -> Surface: ...
def save_extended(surface: Surface, filename: FileArg, namehint: str = "") -> None: ...
```

At first I thought it was the difference between `.pyi` and `.py` files, but it appears no different in my terminal:

```
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  2 2023, 13:45:54) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ...
Ellipsis
>>> pass
>>> Ellipsis
Ellipsis
>>>
```

What does this actually mean? And should I use it in my scripts?
I managed to figure out `.pyi` files are *stubs* for when c libraries are there, it helps things like VSCode show the function args.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do). Per the answers over there, using an ellipsis as a no-op body is a convention for [stub files](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files)

Comment: What do you mean by "it appears no different in my terminal"? `pass` has no result but `...` evaluates to `Ellipsis`.

Comment: Did you read the docs? [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) and [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements)

Comment: @wjandrea. Yeah, but the user types `…`, not `return …`, so with both pass and ellipsis the function returns None.

Comment: @Frank Function? I'm talking about the terminal snippet at the bottom.